# Comparing an element in a linked list with the rest of the list python

Tags: python, linked-list

so I'm having trouble with the current problem I am working on. The problem prompts us to take a linked list and compare each element with the rest of the list and return total number of duplicates. For example the list is [1,2,3,1,4,2,] this should return 2 duplicates 1 and 2. I tried looping through the list using the length of the list but I still get the wrong output. I've provided my attempt below, thanks for any help in advance.

```
def solution1 (llist):
  counter = 0
  length=0
  curr = llist.head

  while curr:
   length+=1
   curr=curr.next

  while curr:
    for _ in range(length):
      if curr.item == curr.next.item:
        counter+=1
    curr = curr.next
 

  return counter
```

Expected Output--

```
llist= 1-->2-->3-->1-->4-->2

output:2
```

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet to the output that you wish to have, instead of in text format.

Comment: Done added at the bottom of code

Comment: That means you are wanting the number f duplicates in the list?

Comment: If your wanting the number of dupes in your list you can perform some simple arthemetics on it, like subtract the total len of list to the len of the unique elements in a list, likewise- ```len(lst)-len(set(lst))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. Below is a brute force approach using nested loops. Maintain two counters `first` and `second`. Whenever their values match, then it means it's a duplicate. Increment the counter and continue.

**Time Complexity: O(n^2)**

```
def solution1(llist):
    counter = 0
    first = llist.head
    
    while first:
        second = first.next
        while second:
            if first.item == second.item: # duplicate
                counter += 1
                break
            second = second.next
        first = first.next      
    return counter
```

A more optimal approach would be to keep count of elements as you iterate. Return keys which have count > 1.

**Time Complexity: O(n)**

```
import collections
def solution1(llist):
    curr = llist.head
    counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
    while curr:
        counts[curr.item] += 1
        curr = curr.next
    print(counts)
    return sum(1 for i in counts if counts[i] > 1)
```